# Solving $n$-SAT and #$n$-SAT

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, sat, counting-complexity

Let $F$ be an $n$–SAT formula on $n$ variables (ie a CNF formula containing exclusively total clauses, with all variables in each), and let $c$ be the number of different clauses in $F$ ($c \le 2^n$).

It is immediate that $F$ is satisfiable iff $c < 2^n$.
It is also easy to show that the number $m$ of models of $F$ is equal to  $2^n - c$.

My questions are then:

Why #$n$-SAT on $n$ variables is not #P-complete? (Why $n$-SAT on $n$ variables is not NP-complete? - Edit : This question has been answered)

Comment: $k$-SAT allows for more than $k$ variables. You appear to only give special cases of $k$-SAT.

Comment: Your "n-SAT" problem is just asking if all possible $2^n$ clauses are present. For this problem to be $NP$-complete, you would have to be able to reduce unsatisfiable instances of $SAT$ to *polynomial size* unsat instances of this problem. But an instance of "n-SAT" is only unsatisfiable when the number of variables is less than $\log N$, where $N$ is the input length. So your polynomial time reduction would have to decrease the number of variables from $N$ to logarithmic in $N$... good luck!

Comment: @RyanWilliams sounds like an answer to me :)

Comment: A simpler way to think about "n-SAT" is that each $n$-variable clause forbids precisely one assignment to the $n$ variables.  Obviously there are $2^n$ possible assignments.

Comment: @AndrasSalamon : Right. Is it a proof of non #P-completness ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your "n-SAT" problem is just asking if all possible $2^n$ clauses are present. For this problem to be $NP$-complete, you would have to be able to reduce unsatisfiable instances of SAT to polynomial size unsatisfiable instances of this problem.

But an instance of "n-SAT" is only unsatisfiable when the number of variables is at most $\log N$, where $N$ is the input length (analogously, when the number of clauses is at least $2^n$, where $n$ is the number of variables). So your polynomial time reduction would have to decrease the number of variables from $N$ to logarithmic in $N$... good luck!

**UPDATE:** You ask why your set *isn't* NP-complete. Note that this is a loaded question. Your set is in $P$, as established earlier. If $P=NP$ then *every* nontrivial set $S$ that's in $P$ is actually $NP$-complete (nontrivial means: there is at least one string $x \in S$ and one string $y \notin S$). If $P=NP$ we have a polytime SAT algorithm. To reduce SAT to $S$, just call the SAT algorithm and output $x$ if your SAT algorithm says "yes", $y$ if it says "no". So to *prove* to you that your $S \in P$ *cannot* be $NP$-complete is tantamount to proving $P \neq NP$!

Comment: Tks for your answer. I understand that "just asking if all possible clauses are present" cannot be NP-complete. That means that this n-SAT problem cannot be so. That is also true for (n-1)-SAT problem, and by recurrence, for any k≤n like k = 3. What to think then ? And what to answer to the #n-SAT part of the first question ?

Comment: I believe a reduction from #2-SAT is possible.

Comment: #2-SAT is #P-complete, which reduces to any #$k$-SAT fairly trivially. However, your problem does not seem to be #P-complete (see Andras's comment).

Comment: But what about the polynomial reduction from k-SAT on n variables to (k+1)-SAT on the same n variables? How can the recurrence stop before reaching the ultimate possible k (which is n) ?

Comment: What is the reduction from $k$-SAT to $(k+1)$-SAT on the same $n$ variables?

Comment: @TimothySun : Each k-clause is transformed in a conjunction of two (k+1) clauses by adding a missing variable in one clause and its negation in the other.

Comment: Oh okay. But your definition of "2-SAT" is not 2-SAT.

Comment: @TimothySun : Sorry to keep asking, but what is the problem with the definition of k-SAT ?

Comment: You can have more than $k$ variables in $k$-SAT.

Comment: @TimothySun : Of course. Does it mean that _k_ -SAT on _n_ variables is not NP-complete ?

Comment: $k$-SAT for $k \geq 3$ is NP-complete.

Comment: @TimothySun : Of course, and k-SAT on n variables is still NP-complete, and k-SAT on n variables is reducible to (K+1)-SAT on n variables, and the question of understanding where (and how) the recurrence stops remains.

Comment: Oh, I misread what you wrote earlier. $k$-SAT on $n$ variables is not NP-complete because the language is (more or less) finite.

Comment: Also, your polytime reduction goes from a problem in P to another problem in P.

Comment: @RyanWilliams : tks for your uptade which makes definitively clearer to me the issue.